# Where do moderators come from?

Tags: discussion, moderation, nominations

A recent comment asked "I wonder what happened to [EndangeredMassa](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/106/endangeredmassa)"?

So, I followed the breadcrumbs, and found someone with a moderator diamond and 188 rep points. So now I'm confused.

Comment: "How is moderator formed?"

Comment: When a Jeff and Joel love each other very much...

Comment: From a stork​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.

Comment: from moderator town.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moderators are nominated and voted on by the community.

Either [through the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/welcome-new-community-moderators/) or on [Meta itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/vote-for-super-user-moderator-poll).

All moderators of SO, SF and SU are also Meta mods.

Meta only mods [Joel Coehoorn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) and [EndangeredMassa](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/106/endangeredmassa) were [transplanted from UserVoice](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/).

Meta only mods [Kyle Cronin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/658/kyle-cronin) and [Tom Ritter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8435/tom-ritter) were subsumed, brought in, after having created sites of their own that went out of the way to provide SOFU support/discussion.

Comment: Joel Coehoorn and EndangeredMassa were from UserVoice, but Tom Ritter and myself were selected when Meta was created

Answer (score 11):

First you need an epic norse god as the father
[image: Techno Viking]
<sub>(source: [geekadelphia.com](http://geekadelphia.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/techno_viking.jpg))</sub>

Then a popular internet figurehead as the mother
[image: boxxy]

Then you incubate for 9 months, and out comes [a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8435/tom-ritter)!

Comment: Boxxy is your mom? You's trollin'.

Comment: ... Who's Boxxy?

Answer (score -4):

When Jeff and the community love each other very much .....

Comment: Joel said that. In 2009. Don't take credit, it's not nice.

Comment: @rlb I changed it slightly. And I actually didn't see it lol.