# What happened to the original four Meta Stack Exchange moderators?

Tags: support, meta, moderators

In November 2018, Meta Stack Exchange received its first set of community moderators since the Meta Stack Overflow-Meta Stack Exchange split (which saw this site being renamed from the former to the latter, and a new per-site meta being established for Stack Overflow).

Prior to that, all moderators of the Trilogy sites (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User) were moderators of this site, in addition to SE staff.

After some research (and my noticing some old "moderator" actions on deleted posts by people who were never Trilogy moderators or Stack Exchange staff), I noticed that this site [had a set of four moderators who exclusively moderated this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32971/377214) (rather than being a staff member or a Trilogy moderator). Two of them were appointed as a result of their past activity on the UserVoice site that preceded this site ([Joel Coehoorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) and [EndangeredMassa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/106/endangeredmassa)), and the other two ([Kyle Cronin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/658/kyle-cronin) and [Tom Ritter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/8435/tom-ritter)) were brought in as they had created external "meta" sites.

What happened to these four moderators? Did they all retire? Were their privileges revoked once the split happened? Were they removed for inactivity?

Comment: "privileges revoked once the split happened" - kind of, not directly. More like "not copied to the new site", as far as I can tell, and they were still mods on SO/MSO. Might be mistaken, hence only comment.

Comment: @Shadow This site *was* Meta Stack Overflow back in those days. When the split happened, the only things *technically* that happened were that it was renamed and redesigned. A whole new per-site meta was created for SO.

Comment: The title is a clickbait, it's misleading to visitors who know nothing about the backstory of Meta SE and Meta SO. It *looks* as if you're referring to four mods who have either recently resigned or were dismissed, it's only when users read the  post they realise you're talking about something that ***happened in 2010***. Nine years ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EndangeredMassa and Tom Ritter were both removed as moderators near the end of 2010. You're probably not going to find information as to why because it was so long ago.

The other two were removed during the Meta split, simply because all moderators were removed as part of that.

Comment: Now that community moderators are being re-appointed these days, is it possible for any of them (especially the latter two, who seem to still be active to this day) to request their privileges back, or will they have to wait to be appointed in the same manner as new mods?

Comment: @Soinic "re-appointed"?? Is this new? One was kicked as part of the saga, one quit as result and I didn't see any of this mentioned anywhere by staff.

Comment: @Shadow Omit the "re-" and my comment will make sense. I meant to delete that, but forgot to.