# When were moderators appointed in MSE for the first time? Is it December 2013 or November 2018?

Tags: support, bug, meta, moderators

If we look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators, this is shown:

[image]

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318630), they were appointed for the first time on November 21, 2018. But, [ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/59303/chrisf)'s appointment date is mentioned as March 12, 2013. Is this a bug?

Does this issue have anything to do with this: [Stack Overflow is getting a Meta of its own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the early years, when this place was still called Meta Stack Overflow, moderatorship here came as a bonus:

> All moderators of SO, SF and SU are also Meta mods.

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32971/295232))

ChrisF was [elected as a Stack Overflow moderator in March 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4), so he was moderator of this site (or its predecessor) for a while, until the MSO/MSE split in 2014, and then again since 2018.

Whether that page should show the earliest or the latest appointment date, that's perhaps another discussion, but it's [consistent with how it's displayed for retired moderators who return later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371581/295232).

Comment: Worth to mention when the split happened, so we know which years Meta ran without any mods. :)

Comment: Well, more of it was moderated by staff. In theory mods 'can' do moderation here but its limited for all sorts of reasons

Comment: "*but it's consistent with how it's displayed for retired moderators who return later.*" Can you please give few examples?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek What do you exactly mean by "*limited*" in the context?

Comment: Here's the staff comment regarding showing the oldest record: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371581/the-elected-in-20xx-link-on-the-moderators-tab-does-not-show-the-most-recent-e#comment1241289_371581. I did bring up the confusion regarding this specific mod in a reply.

Comment: @RandomPerson they can, but depending on the current company politics, they 'can't' or 'don't'

Comment: See also this [chat conversation](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9053911#9053911) in which the user who requested the change in private moderator space came forward.